# WP CPT template not found when another CPT is active/public = true

Tags: custom-post-types

I have 2 custom post types in my WordPress theme, and never had any problems before when both are set to;

```
'public' => 'true'
```

However on this occasion, whenever I set one to true the other one refused to load the template and I a 404 error, I've flushed the cache and still no success.

I've checked through the code and can't see any errors.

```
add_action("init", "custom_post_type_menu_wp_admin");
function custom_post_type_menu_wp_admin() {

register_post_type('developments', 
    array(
        'label' => __('Developments','templatic'),
        'labels' => array(  
            'name' => __('Developments','templatic'),
            'singular_name' => __('Developments','templatic'),
            'add_new' => __('Add Developments','templatic'),
            'add_new_item'=> __('Add New Developments','templatic'),
            'edit' => __('Edit','templatic'),
            'edit_item'=> __('Edit Developments','templatic'),
            'new_item' => __('New Developments','templatic'),
            'view_item' => __('View Developments','templatic'),
            'search_items' => __('Search Developments','templatic'),
            'not_found' => __('No Developments','templatic'),
            'not_found_in_trash'=> __('No Developments found in trash','templatic')   
        ),
        'public'            => true,
        'can_export'        => true,
        'show_ui'           => true,
        '_builtin'          => false,
        '_edit_link'        => 'post.php?post=%d',
        'capability_type'   => 'post',
        'menu_icon'         => 'dashicons-hammer',
        'hierarchical'      => false,
        'rewrite'           => array(
                                        "slug" => "developments",
                                        "with_front" => false
                                    ),
        'query_var'         => "true",
        'supports'          => array(   
                                        'title'
                                    ),
        'show_in_nav_menus' => true
    )
); 

register_post_type('house_types', 
    array(
            'label' => __('House Types','templatic'),
            'labels' => array(  'name' => __('House Types','templatic'),
            'singular_name' => __(
            'House Types','templatic'),
            'add_new' => __('Add House Types','templatic'),
            'add_new_item'=> __('Add New House Types','templatic'),
            'edit' => __('Edit','templatic'),
            'edit_item'=> __('Edit House Types','templatic'),
            'new_item' => __('New House Types','templatic'),
            'view_item' => __('View House Types','templatic'),
            'search_items' => __('Search House Types','templatic'),
            'not_found' => __('No House Types','templatic'),
            'not_found_in_trash'=> __('No House Types found in trash','templatic')   
        ),
        'public'            => true,
        'can_export'        => true,
        'show_ui'           => true, // UI in admin panel
        '_builtin'          => false, // It's a custom post type, not built in
        '_edit_link'        => 'post.php?post=%d',
        'capability_type'   => 'post',
        'menu_icon'         => 'dashicons-admin-multisite',
        'hierarchical'      => false, // Sets parent, child effect. Needs 'page-attributes' setting up
        'rewrite'           => array(
                                        "slug" => "house-types",
                                        "with_front" => false
                                    ), // Permalinks
        'query_var'         => "true", // This goes to the WP_Query schema
        'supports'          => array(   
                                        'title'
                                    ) ,
        'show_in_nav_menus' => true 
    )
); 
}
```

Can anyone spot what's gone wrong on this occasion, please?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You've flushed the cache, but have you flushed your permalinks? If not, or if you're not sure, you can go to **Settings » Permalinks** in the admin pages, and click **Save Changes**.

Comment: Hi @PatJ sorry, should've added that part, yes flushed cache and permalinks

Comment: Please [edit your question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/posts/350734/edit) to show any code that you're using to define the template, then (eg, if you're filtering [`template_include`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/template_include/)).